# I can't convert tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor to tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor (In keras loss function)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensor, loss-function

I have this loss function

```
LossList={0:1,1:0,2:3,3:2}
def myLoss(y_true,y_pred):
    y_pred=tf.cast(y_pred, dtype=tf.float32)
    y_true=tf.cast(y_true, dtype=tf.float32)
    losses2=np.mean([tf.gather(pred,l2.numpy().astype(int)) for l2,pred in zip(tf.map_fn(lambda row:LossList[np.argmax(row)],y_true),y_pred)])*0.25
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(y_pred-y_true))+losses2
```

This loos function working in this code

```
myLoss([[0,1,0,0]],[[0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25]])  # output: 0.375
```

I passed this loss function to `keras.Sequantial(models)`

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=myLoss)
```

And I want to fit my model

```
model.fit(X_train,NewYTrain,epochs=10,validation_data=(X_test,NewYTest),steps_per_epoch=32)
```

and this is the output:

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[81], line 1
----> 1 model.fit(X_train,NewYTrain,epochs=10,validation_data=(X_test,NewYTest),steps_per_epoch=32)

File c:\Users\10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filemojf8nwq.py:15, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__train_function(iterator)
     13 try:
     14     do_return = True
---> 15     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16 except:
     17     do_return = False

File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filexorsfjg1.py:15, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__myLoss(y_true, y_pred)
     13 ag__.ld(print)(ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(dir), (ag__.ld(y_pred),), None, fscope))
     14 ag__.ld(print)(ag__.ld(y_pred).value_index)
---> 15 y_pred = ag__.converted_call(ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).cast, (ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).convert_to_tensor, (ag__.ld(y_pred),), None, fscope),), dict(dtype=ag__.ld(tf).float32), fscope).numpy, (), None, fscope)
     16 y_true = ag__.converted_call(ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).cast, (ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).convert_to_tensor, (ag__.ld(y_true),), None, fscope),), dict(dtype=ag__.ld(tf).float32), fscope).numpy, (), None, fscope)
...
    File "C:\Users\10\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_5292\1586549603.py", line 8, in myLoss  *
        y_pred=tf.cast(tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred), dtype=tf.float32).numpy()

    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

I have debugged my code and I understand that type y_pred and y_true are `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor`. they should be `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor`.

This does not work:

```
y_true=tf.convert_to_tensor(y_true)
y_pred=tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred)
```

Comment: Hi @poya, You need to install and import the numpy module to fix this issue as you have used numpy in custom loss function and you might not have imported numpy before using. You can use this code for the same - `pip install numpy`, `import numpy`.